# Sympy .replace() doesn't detect product

Tags: sympy

I'm trying to make some replacements, but `.replace()` is confusingly missing occurrences:

```
from sympy import *
x, y = symbols('x y')
f = Function('f')

expr = x*f(x)*f(y)
expr.replace(x*f(x), 1)

# Output: x*f(x)*f(y)
# Expected: f(y)
```

Is this a bug?

It *does* work when I use `.subs()` instead of `.replace()`, but I have no idea why this would be needed.
(also, I wanna use this in the context of a `Sum` expression where `.subs()` would not work).

Comment: From the `replace` docs it isn't obvious that it should work as you expect. That said, I have used `subs` but not `replace`.

Comment: @hpaulj, can you explain how this is not clear from the docs? The docs say "Replace matching subexpressions of self with value". Intuitively, I feel that `x*f(x)` should really be a subexpression of `x*f(x)*f(y)`. Am I overlooking anything?